# Using If and else in JavaScript with data attributes

Tags: javascript

I am having trouble using If and else with data attributes in java script to validate what function should be ran, if you could help me in this issue would be great as been trying to resolve for a bit now.

I currently have the following code:

```
  if($('.currentplayersleaguedatatofind[data-currentplayerDivisoninleague="1"]') == "1"){
    buttonclicked1();
}else if($('.currentplayersleaguedatatofind[data-currentplayerDivisoninleague="2"]') == "2"){
    buttonclicked2();
} else if($('.currentplayersleaguedatatofind[data-currentplayerDivisoninleague="3"]') == "3"){
    buttonclicked3();
} else if($(".currentplayersleaguedatatofind").data("currentplayerDivisoninleague") == "4"){
    buttonclicked4();
} else if($(".currentplayersleaguedatatofind").data("currentplayerDivisoninleague") == "5"){
    buttonclicked5();
}
```

Thanks in Advnace

Comment: You didn't say what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this perhaps

```
  var league = $(".currentplayersleaguedatatofind").data("currentplayerDivisoninleague"),
      actions = {
         "1":buttonclicked1,
         "2":buttonclicked2,
         "3":buttonclicked3,
         "4":buttonclicked4,
         "5":buttonclicked5,
      };

  actions[league]();
```

---

Depending on what `buttonclickX` does you might be able to use a single function that accepts the `league` as a parameter and acts accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check **$('.currentplayersleaguedatatofind')'s** data-currentPlayerDivisioninleague.
In your code

```
$('.currentplayersleaguedatatofind[data-currentplayerDivisoninleague="1"]') == "1")
$('.currentplayersleaguedatatofind[data-currentplayerDivisoninleague="1"]-
```

> this gives the currentPlayers object and that you are comparing with "1" which will never be true.

To compare their values all you have to do is

```
$('.currentplayersleaguedatatofind').data('currentplayerDivisoninleague'])=="1"
```

check this snippet

```js
var currentPlayers = $('.currentplayersleaguedatatofind');
var data = currentPlayers.data('currentplayerDivisoninleague']);

if (data == "1") {
  buttonclicked1();
} else if (data == "2" {
    buttonclicked2();
  } else if (data == "3") {
    buttonclicked3();
  } else if (data == "4") {
    buttonclicked4();
  } else if (data == "5") {
    buttonclicked5();
  }
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks alot will try it now :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare the value of `data` attribute not the object itself. Read the value and then compare . Like this:

```
var currentLeague = $('.currentplayersleaguedatatofind').attr('data-currentplayerDivisoninleague');
if(currentLeague === "1"){
  buttonclicked1();
} else if(currentLeague === "2"){
  buttonclicked2();
} else if(currentLeague === "3"){
  buttonclicked3();
} else if(currentLeague === "4"){
  buttonclicked4();
} else if(currentLeague === "5"){
  buttonclicked5();
}
```